# No visible @interface for 'NSURLRequest' declares the selector 'initwithURL:'

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlrequest

New to Xcode, what's wrong with my coding here?

```
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
Webview.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
[UIWebView loadRequest: [[[NSURLRequest alloc] initwithURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.reddit.com/r/Diecast/"]]];
[super viewDidLoad];
```

Please help, if I did something wrong, correct me!  I'm trying to make a browser for that specific page, so that people can open pictures and browse the page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your capitalization on `-initWithURL:`

Also, you need to call `loadRequest:` on your web view instance, not on the class `UIWebView`:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.reddit.com/r/Diecast/"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[Webview loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: +1 For explaining the change (Not obvious from simply looking at the revised code)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
Webview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[Webview loadRequest: [[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.reddit.com/r/Diecast/"]]];
```

Comment: Didn't work, thanks anyways!